# Build TensorFlow Lite with custom operations

Tags: android, tensorflow, android-ndk, bazel, tensorflow-lite

Following this [article](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/compiling-a-tensorflow-lite-build-with-custom-operations-cf6330ee30e2). At step 4 when executing command

```
bazel build --cxxopt='--std=c++11' -c opt        \
  --fat_apk_cpu=x86,x86_64,arm64-v8a,armeabi-v7a   \
  //tensorflow/lite/java:tensorflow-lite
```

I am getting error. Log output bellow.

```
ERROR: /home/robertas/.cache/bazel/_bazel_robertas/fc35d006e87d344d01f9b09aa9faf335/external/farmhash_archive/BUILD.bazel:12:1: C++ compilation of rule '@farmhash_archive//:farmhash' failed (Exit 127): clang failed: error executing command 
  (cd /home/robertas/.cache/bazel/_bazel_robertas/fc35d006e87d344d01f9b09aa9faf335/execroot/org_tensorflow && \
  exec env - \
    ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=28.0.3 \
    ANDROID_NDK_API_LEVEL=21 \
    ANDROID_NDK_HOME=/home/robertas/opt/android/android-ndk-r15c \
    ANDROID_SDK_API_LEVEL=28 \
    ANDROID_SDK_HOME=/home/robertas/opt/android/sdk \
    PATH=/home/robertas/opt/jdk1.8.0/bin:/home/robertas/opt/android/sdk/platform-tools:/home/robertas/opt/android/sdk/tools:/home/robertas/opt/android/sdk:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin:/home/robertas/.local/bin \
    PWD=/proc/self/cwd \
    PYTHON_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/python \
    PYTHON_LIB_PATH=/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages \
    TF_CONFIGURE_IOS=0 \
    TF_DOWNLOAD_CLANG=1 \
  external/androidndk/ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang '-D__ANDROID_API__=21' -isystemexternal/androidndk/ndk/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -gcc-toolchain external/androidndk/ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-invalid-command-line-argument -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -no-canonical-prefixes -fno-integrated-as -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi '-march=armv7-a' '-mfloat-abi=softfp' '-mfpu=vfpv3-d16' -mthumb -Os -g -DNDEBUG -MD -MF bazel-out/android-armeabi-v7a-opt/bin/external/farmhash_archive/_objs/farmhash/farmhash.pic.d '-frandom-seed=bazel-out/android-armeabi-v7a-opt/bin/external/farmhash_archive/_objs/farmhash/farmhash.pic.o' -fPIC -iquote external/farmhash_archive -iquote bazel-out/android-armeabi-v7a-opt/bin/external/farmhash_archive -isystem external/farmhash_archive/src -isystem bazel-out/android-armeabi-v7a-opt/bin/external/farmhash_archive/src '--std=c++11' '--sysroot=external/androidndk/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-arm' -isystem external/androidndk/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -isystem external/androidndk/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/include -isystem external/androidndk/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward -isystemexternal/androidndk/ndk/sysroot/usr/include -c external/farmhash_archive/src/farmhash.cc -o bazel-out/android-armeabi-v7a-opt/bin/external/farmhash_archive/_objs/farmhash/farmhash.pic.o)
Execution platform: @bazel_tools//platforms:host_platform
external/androidndk/ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Target //tensorflow/lite/java:tensorflow-lite failed to build
```

Environment: Linux, Manjaro Illyria 18.0.4

How this can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Issue occurred because Manjaro had installed package **ncurses version 6.1-6**. Installing package **ncurses5-compat-libs** from AUR issue was solved.